# Node.js: Sending form requests on websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, request

I am trying to log in on this page: http://stomfak.ukim.edu.mk/login_student.php using Node.js. I'm using the request external module for this, but can't get it to work as intended. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://stomfak.ukim.edu.mk/login_student.php',
    { form: {
        korime: 'myEmail',
        lozinka: 'myPassword'
    } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

No log from the above.

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://stomfak.ukim.edu.mk/login_student.php',
    { form: {
        korime: 'myEmail',
        lozinka: 'myPassword',
        Submit: 'Најава'
    } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

I tried the above, because I saw that the post request accepts the Submit parameter too, which is always the value of "Најава". No log from the above either.

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://stomfak.ukim.edu.mk/login_student.php',
    { json: {
        korime: 'myEmail',
        lozinka: 'myPassword'
    } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

This only logs the body of the page that contains the form, even when I send the correct credentials.

Sorry about the language of the website, but I hope that won't be an issue.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that way, because it will not fire the event by your request. However,  If you could identify which route does the submit event button, you may be able to put your request to that route, bypassing the form itself  just sending the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what the website requires, I would recommend you to:

- log in the website with inspect mode
- look at the requested header to add more info to your current header.
- Then use Postman to send different requests, and see which one works for you

In postman, there's also a Code link that can generate code in different languages, in your case is nodejs.
Let me know if that works for you